# Circular import in Python with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My project:

```
project_name
|- my_app
   |- __init__.py
|- run.py
|- models.py
```

**First example**

run.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import User
db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

models.py

```
from run import db

class User(db.Model):
    #...
```

__ init.py __ is empty

After running this example I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

This error describe Circular import of app variable in models.py (as I understand).

**Second example**

run.py

```
from my_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

models.py

```
from my_app import db

class User(db.Model):
    #...
```

__ init.p __

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import User
db.create_all()
```

And now all works correct.

And, at this point, I don't understand, why the same code give me different logic?

Where is the magic? Why Circular import in __ init.py __ does't throw an error?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to talk about your first example, because you can actually reproduce both scenarios without changing the code:

Example 1: Run `run.py` directly to see the Import error

Example 2: Open a python repl, and run:

```
from run import app
app.run()
```

And your first example now works, for the same reason your second code example did: the imports were moved out of `__main__`

In example 1, `run.py` is the top level execution environment, and the code here runs in `__main__`. The relative import to `models.py` requires that all references in `models.py` be resolved (since the class you're importing from `models.py` may be dependent on other parts of `models.py` *outside* of the class itself). The first thing `models.py` does is go *back* to `__main__` to perform a relative import of `db`, and since it needs to resolve all references, it does - and one of the references it tries to resolve is the original `from models import user` statement. Voila, ImportError.

The thing is, at this point `run.py` *hasn't finished executing*, and so far it's still trying to import the definition of `User`. But now `models.py` is trying to call into it as though it had finished loading, and it expects `run.py` to already *know* the definition of `User`, even though it's right in the middle of trying to figure that exact thing out!

This isn't a circular import - not really. `models.py` is just trying to import from a file that hasn't finished executing yet, and whose contents aren't available for use.

By moving `__main__` elsewhere - into the repl, or by moving your code around so that run.py doesn't define *anything* - you're giving the code a chance to actually resolve all the dependencies before any code tries to use them. By using `from run import app; app.run()`, **this** is the only code that is *not done executing*. The imports themselves all get to complete their work, resolve their dependencies and make them available to `__main__`

tl;dr don't accidentally write code that imports from `__main__` when `__main__` doesn't yet know the things it's being asked for

Comment: Thank You for answer! If I correct understand, my first example is not working because I try to use circular import in file that is executed?

Comment: @jQuick That's more or less what it boils down to - the important thing to remember is that, the file _being_ executed hasn't resolved all of its definitions yet, so it isn't ready for other files to try to import stuff from it.